# SQLite near "=" syntax error

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un query el cual es el siguiente:

```
String query = "SELECT subjects.id_sbj FROM " + db_name + " WHERE subjects.name_sj = " + value;
```

value contiene: `Test`

Cada vez que corro el query me marca este error: `near "=": syntax error` dentro de ese query y no se porque. `El objetivo es traer el id donde name_sbj = value`

Answer (score 1):

Agrega las comillas que faltan para envolver el valor de value:

```
String query = "SELECT subjects.id_sbj FROM " + db_name + " 
WHERE subjects.name_sj = '" + value + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Como el valor del campo name_sj es `TEXT`, entonces debes usar como contenedor el carácter `'` para indicar que el valor es de este tipo, ejemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE NAME = 'Axel';
```

En el caso de tu query esto sería lo correcto:

```
String query = "SELECT subjects.id_sbj FROM " + db_name + " WHERE subjects.name_sj = '" + value + "'";
```